# IIS has replaced "localhost" when trying to use XAMPP apache server

Tags: iis, xampp, wamp

I'm new to this so please bear with me. I was working with XAMPP one when I tried using WAMP. I didn't like it, so I reverted to XAMPP. However, I noticed that typing in "localhost"in the address bar no longer delivers me to the XAMPP home page, **diverting me instead to IIS Windows**. 127.0.0.1 still work though but I want localhost back if possible.

Another thing, WAMP is already uninstalled

Comment: Well, only one server can listen at a given port. The default port for the `http` protocol is 80. So if IIS already uses port 80 you cannot use the apache http server in parallel on the same port. Either you have to deactivate IIS, or you have to configure apache to bind to another port and use a URL like `http://localhost:8080/` or whatever you chose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To deactivate IIS open Internet Information System (IIS) Manager.
- In the right hand side pane you will see `Actions` pane.
- Click on stop.

Or you can use command prompt as administrator and run this.

```
NET STOP "W3SVC"
```

You can not use Apache http server and IIS to run on same port. i.e 80